# Delegate methods of JTCalendar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, jtcalendar

I am implementing `JTCalendar` in Swift to display event and add event on Calendar. I am able to display calendar. But problem is in implementing its delegate methods.
This is code in Objective-C:

```
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    // Today
    if([_calendarManager.dateHelper date:[NSDate date] isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

This is code in Swift:

```
func calendar(calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: UIView!) {
        if calenderManager.dateHelper.date(NSDate(), isTheSameDayThan: **dayView.date**) {

        }

    }
```

Here `dayView` type is of UIview in Swift in delegate then how I will get date value from delegate method. Also give me support how I can implement delegate methods of JTCalendar.

Comment: Isn't the documentation pretty clear [here](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/wiki/Setup-the-calendar-in-this-quick-tutorial) ?

Comment: I want to show multiple event as JTCalendar open. How i can show same. Which method will be called ? Please help me.

Comment: You want to show multiple event? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Means I am getting some date from server. I want to display all date as event on Calendar.

Comment: Ok i just realized my mistake. I can help you if you are using [JTAppleCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). But you are not using this. You are using JTCalendar.

Comment: @ swift nub : Thankyou for your response. Now i am using JTAppleCalendar. But still not able to display multiple events which I am getting from Server. What i need to do to display multiple events.

Comment: You can display multiple events very easily. First, set your calendar to have multiple events like this :`myCalendar.allowsMultipleSelection = true`. Then all you have to do is select the dates from the server like this: `myCalendar.selectDates(datesFromServer)`. If you need more help, go to [this link here](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/wiki/Common-Questions) and look at answer #4